# Oracle procedure, placement of multiple records in variables

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm trying to create my first oracle procedure. The select will return multiple records; I need to be able to place each record in the variables and use the record in later actions in the procedure. Any help please?

```
   key number;
   keyCount number;
   rub varchar2(50);
   srub varchar2(100);
   type varchar2(200);
   date varchar2(14);
   note varchar2(500);
   BEGIN
      SELECT KEY,COUNT(KEY),RUB,
      SRUB,TYPE ,DATE,NOTE FROM Student
      WHERE S_KEY = {key};

   END;
```

Comment: Oracle documentation for using `INTO` [link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems045.htm) which can be used to store data from table into variables

Answer (score 2):

In PL/SQL we need to select results into matching variables. One way is separate variables for each column (as shown). The alternative is to use a row variable which matches the project of the query; [find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/composites.htm#LNPLS00509).

You've got an aggregating function - `COUNT()` so you need a `GROUP BY` clause which defines the non-aggregating columns. You say you have more than one record so you need to populate a collection not scalar variables. [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/tuning.htm#LNPLS891).

Your procedure should look something like this

```
   create or replace procedure my_first_proc
      ( p_key in student.s_key%type )
   as
     type my_rec is record (
         key number ,
         keyCount number ,
         rub varchar2(50); ,
         srub varchar2(100) ,
         type varchar2(200) ,
         date varchar2(14),
         note varchar2(500)
       );
      type my_rec_coll is table of my_rec;
      l_student_recs my_rec_coll;
   BEGIN
      SELECT KEY,COUNT(KEY),RUB,SRUB,TYPE ,DATE,NOTE   
      bulk collect into   l_student_recs 
      FROM Student
      WHERE S_KEY = p_key
      group by  KEY,RUB,SRUB,TYPE ,DATE,NOTE 
      ;
      for idx in l_student_recs.first() .. l_student_recs.last()
      loop
          -- do some processing here
          dbms_output.put_line('RUB = '||l_student_recs(idx).rub);
      end loop;
   EXCEPTION
        when no_data_found then
             raise_application_error(-01403, 'no student records for key='||p_key);
   END;
```

Get into good habits:

- use sensible variable names
- distinguish parameter names from local variables
- handle predictable exceptions